# error: function was not declared in the scope

Tags: c++

I have a class named logs_i with a virtual fucntion which named begin_record;
I had to write a new class named counter_logs_t which supposed to has a method which counts the logs.

Here is the interface and the implemantation of counter_logs_t:

```
class counter_logs_t : public log_i
{
public:
    counter_logs_t(int counter);
    void print_counter(void);
    void add_counter(void);
    virtual void begin_record(void);

private:
    int counter;
};

counter_logs_t::counter_logs_t(int counter) : log_i()
{
    counter = 0;
}

void counter_logs_t::add_counter(void)
{
    counter++;
}

void logs_t::begin_record(void)
{
    log_i::begin_record();
    add_counter();
}


void counter_logs_t::print_counter(void){
    cout<< counter<< endl;
}

int main()
{

        counter_logs_t  container1();
//some code
        container1.print_counter();

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to build I got the following error:
error: 'add_counter' was not declared in the scope

Comment: `add_counter` is a method on `counter_logs_t`, but it's called from `logs_t:begin_record `, `logs_t` doesn't know `add_counter`

Comment: [Should I use f(void) or f()?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#void-in-param-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of this function is incorrect, specifically the class name

```
void logs_t::begin_record(void)
```

I think you meant

```
void counter_logs_t::begin_record(void)
```

Edit:

Your second issue is that you ran into [the most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work) on this line

```
counter_logs_t  container1();
```

This is interpreted as declaring a function named `container1` that takes no arguments and returns a `coutner_logs_t`. In fact, there is no default-constructor for `counter_logs_t`, the only constructor has the following signature

```
counter_logs_t(int counter);
```

Therefore you have to construct it with a `counter` argument.

```
counter_logs_t container1{0};
counter_logs_t container1 = counter_logs_t(0);
```

Or make a default constructor

```
counter_logs_t::counter_logs_t() : log_i(), counter(0) {}
```

then you can just say

```
counter_logs_t container1;
```

Comment: @CoryKraner- thanks. But now I get the following error "error: request for member "print_counter' in 'container1' , which is of none-class type '...

Comment: @CoryKraner- again thanks....I tries the forst option (with the{}), and got the following error "error: no matching function for call to 'counter_logs_t :: counter_logs_t <brace-enclosed...

Comment: @SaritRotshild See my latest edit, your class has no default constructor.

Comment: @CoryKraner- why can't I use "counter_logs_t container1;"? I mase a default constructor in                                       counter_logs_t::counter_logs_t(int counter) : log_i()
{
    counter = 0;
}                                                                                                                  It's also initailization no?!

Comment: @SaritRotshild No you didn't make a default constructor. A default constructor takes no arguments. The constructor you just stated takes an `int` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You also have an issue where

```
counter_logs_t container1();
```

Is not declaring a variable.  It declares a function named `container1` that reutrns a `counter_logs_t` and takes nothing.  You need to change it to

```
counter_logs_t container1;
```

To declare a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
void logs_t::begin_record(void)
{
    log_i::begin_record();
    add_counter();
}
```

in this function:
1. "logs_t" should be "counter_logs_t".
2. i don't recommend you to call class log_i's method `begin_record()` using  "::" operator, unless you know it's a static method. You'd better call it like this `this->begin_record` for it's a virtual method.